# Invalid formula - Operator "+" doesn't support TEXT + NUMBER. Operator "+" supports NUMBER + NUMBER

Tags: looker-studio

This was working last week but now it has an error like this:

> Invalid formula - Operator "+" doesn't support TEXT + NUMBER. Operator "+" supports NUMBER + NUMBER

Current formula:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE
    WHEN First Duration+Second Duration<=24 THEN New ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) / COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE
    WHEN First Duration IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN Second Duration IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE New ID
  END )
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the issue on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test out the issue. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint where the issue lies, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage...**

Answer (score -1):

I can only recommend checking that the `First Duration` and `Second Duration` dimensions are fields in the type number format. Otherwise, you can change it manually or create a new field to format the text dimension into a number.

I had problems where a field of type number or date, after a database update, was interpreted by Google Data Studio in text format. Apparently your formula doesn't have any syntax errors, only the dimensions used don't seem to follow the recommended format.